# I use [WebMethod] , just want to ask if this is what they call WebService?

Tags: asp.net, webmethod

In my C# code behind, I have a WebMethod like this

```
  //Get total Sales monthly
  [WebMethod]
  public static List<object> getTotalSales(){
     //lines of codes;
  }
```

My question is, am I doing the thing called web service? I used the returned value in front end (aspx page), which is called by my jQuery ajax function in an aspx file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a webservice by itself, by creating an `.asmx` page.

What you're doing here is turning a public method in your page into a webservice.

So the short answer to your question, is yes, you're doing a thing called webservice. And you can then call it in your client via ajax.

[This article elaborates on this.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @Oliver: Technically, I am doing a webservice based from your answer. But is this an acceptable practice or I must create a asmx file? thank you

Comment: Totally acceptable. I have used this on many sites. However, nowadays Microsoft is coming up with new technologies such as Web API. But this is still acceptable and will work.

Comment: so the term Web API is now the new tech of doing a webservice, if I understand it correctly. Is web api totally different or same approach as webservice/webmethod?

Answer (score 1):

The web service is the *`WebService`* object or ASMX file that is accessible via the `WebMethod`s.

Comment: so what is the answer to my question? Sorry but I'm confused. I don't have asmx file. but my webmethod works when called by jQuery

Comment: If you are using _WebMethod_ 's then yes, you are using a web service.